# How to discard scheduled celery tasks if their execution in the queue gets delayed by a maximum time period ?

Tags: python, python-3.x, celery

Scenario:

1. Tasks get queued in celery through the celerybeat schedule at specific time.
2. In certain rare scenarios, the celery tasks queues might be long, or tasks may take more than normal to finish.
3. Lets assume few task gets scheduled in the queue at 3am, and mostly finish by 4am by the workers.Let's assume 5 am to be a time limit.
4. In certain scenarios, the execution of fore-mentioned tasks reaches 6am.
   How to discard all the tasks currently queued, if the time is past 5am now ? i.e. a task already queued sometime back shall not run if the current time has crossed a time_of_day condition.

An obvious method would be to use `datetime` module within the celery tasks code and return if they are past the time_of_day conditions.

Is there any inbuilt method/parameter in celery to control this behaviour ? What would be a better way to achieve this ?